# Spring batch : Default the values for empty fields (double and char) when using a FieldSetMapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, default-value

I am currently using Spring batch for reading a file. There is a possibility that certain columns in my file may have empty values. For example, a row in my file may look like this :

```
110045,,,50000
```

Here, column 2 and 3 have empty values. Column 2 will be mapped to a double and column 3 will be mapped to a char in my domain object. The `FieldSetMapper` will be implemented as follows :

```
public class MyFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<SomeDomain> {

    public SomeDomain mapFieldSet(FieldSet fs) {
        final SomeDomain someDomain = new SomeDomain();
        someDomain.setAmount(fs.readDouble(1));
        someDomain.setIndividualFlag(fs.readChar(2));
        someDomain.setBalance(fs.readInt(3,0));
        return someDomain;
    }
}
```

The `FieldSetMapper`implementation above will result in an exception at runtime because an empty `String` cannot be convered to a double or a character.

While a `FieldSet` has methods such as `readBigDecimal(int,BigDecimal)` or `readInt(int,int)` that allow you to specify a default value if a string can't be parsed to a particular type, it does not provide similar methods for `char` or `double`. I am not sure what was the motivation behind leaving the defaulting options out for `char` and `double` types.

What I need is a way to provide a default value for `char` and `double` datatypes in a `FieldSetMapper` per field. That is, I **don't want to define a global strategy** for defaulting `char` and `double` datatypes but I want to be able to default these types just like I can default an `int` or a `BigDecimal`.

I thought of using a `FieldSetFactory` to plugin a custom `FieldSet` implementation that extends `DefaultFieldSet` and provides two more methods namely `readDouble(int,double)` and `readChar(int,char)`

```
public class CustomFieldSet extends DefaultFieldSet {

    public CustomFieldSet(String[] tokens, String[] names) {
        super(tokens, names);
    }

    public CustomFieldSet(String[] tokens) {
        super(tokens);
    }

    public char readChar(int index, char defaultValue) {
        String value = readAndTrim(index);
        return StringUtils.hasLength(value) ? value.charAt(0) : defaultValue;
    }

    public int readChar(String name, char defaultValue) {
        return readChar(indexOf(name), defaultValue);
    }
}
```

I could then cast the `FieldSet` argument that the `mapFieldSet` method takes into a `CustomFieldSet` implementation

```
public class MyFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<SomeDomain> {

  public SomeDomain mapFieldSet(FieldSet fs) {
       CustomFieldSet cs = (CustomFieldSet)fs;
       final SomeDomain someDomain = new SomeDomain();
       someDomain.setAmount(cs.readDouble(1));
       someDomain.setIndividualFlag(cs.readChar(2,'\0'));
       someDomain.setBalance(cs.readInt(3,0));
       return someDomain;
   }
}
```

This somehow doesn't feel like the right thing to do even though it integrates seamlessly with the spring batch `FieldSet` API.,

What are my options if I want to default `char` and `double` types in an elegant way rather than reading them as `String`, checking if they are not empty and converting them to the specific type manually.

Comment: Did you find the solution?